# scrape table to excel file

Tags: python, html

I am struggling to data scrape this website:

https://wix-visual-data.appspot.com/app/widget?pageId=cu7nt&compId=comp-kesofw00&viewerCompId=comp-kesofw00&siteRevision=947&viewMode=site&deviceType=desktop&locale=en&tz=Europe%2FLondon&width=980&height=890&instance=k983l1LiiUeOz5_3Pd_CLXbjfadc08q1fEu54xfh9aA.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&currency=GBP&currentCurrency=GBP&vsi=795183b4-8f30-4854-bd85-77678dbe4cf8&consent-policy=%7B%22func%22%3A0%2C%22anl%22%3A0%2C%22adv%22%3A0%2C%22dt3%22%3A1%2C%22ess%22%3A1%7D&commonConfig=%7B%22brand%22%3A%22wix%22%2C%22bsi%22%3Anull%2C%22BSI%22%3Anull%7D

This URL has a table but for some reason I am not able to scrape this into an excel file. This is my current code in Python and this is what I have tried. Any help is much appreciated thank you legends!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://wix-visual-data.appspot.com/app/widget?pageId=cu7nt&compId=comp-kesofw00&viewerCompId=comp-kesofw00&siteRevision=947&viewMode=site&deviceType=desktop&locale=en&tz=Europe%2FLondon&width=980&height=890&instance=dxGyx3zK9ULK0A8UtGOrLw-__FTD9EBEfzQojJ7Bz00.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&currency=GBP&currentCurrency=GBP&vsi=57130cda-8191-488e-8089-f472928266e3&consent-policy=%7B%22func%22%3A0%2C%22anl%22%3A0%2C%22adv%22%3A0%2C%22dt3%22%3A1%2C%22ess%22%3A1%7D&commonConfig=%7B%22brand%22%3A%22wix%22%2C%22bsi%22%3Anull%2C%22BSI%22%3Anull%7D")

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

table = soup.find_all('table', {'id':'theTable'})
print(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to scrape the table, because you are scraping the html of the table. Each row of the table is wrapped in a `<tr>` and each column value is wrapped in a `<td>` within the `<tr>`. So you need to loop over each row and append each value to create a nested list of lists, in which each list is a row.

```
url = "https://wix-visual-data.appspot.com/app/widget?pageId=cu7nt&compId=comp-kesofw00&viewerCompId=comp-kesofw00&siteRevision=947&viewMode=site&deviceType=desktop&locale=en&tz=Europe%2FLondon&width=980&height=890&instance=dxGyx3zK9ULK0A8UtGOrLw-__FTD9EBEfzQojJ7Bz00.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&currency=GBP&currentCurrency=GBP&vsi=57130cda-8191-488e-8089-f472928266e3&consent-policy=%7B%22func%22%3A0%2C%22anl%22%3A0%2C%22adv%22%3A0%2C%22dt3%22%3A1%2C%22ess%22%3A1%7D&commonConfig=%7B%22brand%22%3A%22wix%22%2C%22bsi%22%3Anull%2C%22BSI%22%3Anull%7D"
driver.get(url)
#Wait for page to fully load
time.sleep(2)
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
#Get html of table
table = soup.find('table', {'id':'theTable'})
#Find all rows
rows = table.find_all('tr')
tabledata = []
#Loop over rows, skipping the first one, which is the class statement
for row in rows[1:]:
    #Find column values in each row and append to tabledata
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [col.text.strip() for col in cols]
    tabledata.append([col for col in cols if col])

df = pd.DataFrame(tabledata, columns=['Player Name and Rating', 'Target Buy Price (Max)', 'Target Selling Price (Min)', '% From Buy Price', 'Current Market Price (Est)'])
df.to_excel("tablescrape.xlsx", index=False)
```